# $n$-sided die thrown $n$ times. Probability that sum of results equals sum of prime factors of $n$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> We roll an $n$-sided fair die $n$ times. What is the probability that the sum of the results is equal to the sum of the prime factors of $n$?
>
> That is, if $q_i$, $i \in {0,1,2,\ldots,n}$ is the result of the $i$th-throw and $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_m^{k_m}$ then what is the probability that $\sum_1^n q_i=\sum_1^m p_j$?

Is this question valid for arbitrary $n$? I did some testing with small $n$, but I have difficulty generalizing the problem for any $n$.

Comment: Might be appropriate to share the results of the testing that you have conducted for small values of $n$.

Comment: Start with this: what's the answer if $n$ is prime? The square of a prime?

Comment: The answer depends on the prime factorization of $n$, and that changes drastically every time you increment $n$ by $1$, so the answer as a function of $n$ should behave rather erratically. $\qquad$

Comment: @barakmanos I tried with really small values $(n<20)$. Unfortunately my programming skills are not up to the task. If one could apply an algorithm covering large $n$, say up to $1000$ something more interesting might appear.

Comment: @MichaelHardy So I guess because of the erratic behaviour it would be a dead end trying to find some sort of a closed form? And the problem has meaning (is worth attempting to solve) only for a particular $n$?

Comment: @EthanBolker $1/p^p$ in general if we have a power of $p$?

Comment: The sum of the dice throws is at least $n$.  The sum of the prime factors is less than $n$ for all except prime $n$, when the probability is $(1/n)^n$ that each of the $n$ throws is 1.

Comment: See @AndrásSalamon 's comment ...

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake : I doubt there would be a closed form but maybe one can say something about asymptotics. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for taking the time to adress the problem! An answer was posted below that I think covers it, giving essentially a closed form. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $xy > x+y$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are distinct integers that are at least 2.
It then follows that $n \ge \prod_{i=1}^m p_i > \sum_{i=1}^m p_i$ if $m\ge 2$ or $k_1\ge 2$, and $n = \prod_{i=1}^m p_i = \sum_{i=1}^m p_i$ when $m=1$ and $k_1=1$.
On the other hand, the sum of the dice rolls is always at least $n$.
So the only way the condition is satisfied is if $n$ is prime, and then only if each of the dice throws results in 1, a probability of $(1/n)^n$.